# Elasticsearch : How get result buckets size

Tags: elasticsearch, statistics, bucket

Here is my query result

```
GET _search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "serviceName.keyword": "directory-view-service"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "path": "thewall"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "from": "now-31d",
              "to": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date",
        "interval": "7d"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "byUserUid": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "token_userId.keyword",
            "size": 150000
          },
          "aggs": {
            "filterByCallNumber": {
              "bucket_selector": {
                "buckets_path": {
                  "doc_count": "_count"
                },
                "script": {
                  "inline": "params.doc_count <= 1"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want my query return all user call my endpoint min. once time by 1 month range by 7 days interval, *until then everything is good*.

**But my result is a buckets with 370 elements and I just need to know the array size...**

Are there any keyword or how can I handle it ?

Thanks

Comment: You want to get size of buckets? Don’t you just parsing json and getting this information from there?

Comment: @Mysterion I can't beceause my JSON have 365 array (each day) each containing 400 elements and I need to compare each elements of each array between them. I've this result : 
` buckets: [ buckets:[ {key: user_uid} ] <-- this 365 times ] ` 
and I need compare each day for see user is there each days